# Setting array value as a list

Tags: tcl

I am having trouble with this snippet of code:

```
    set rect(1) [list 0 0 $x1 $y1]
    set rect(2) [list $x1 0 $x2 $y1]
    set rect(3) [list $x2 0 $x3 $y1]
    set rect(4) [list 0 $y1 $x1 $y2]
    set rect(5) [list $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2]
    set rect(6) [list $x2 $y1 $x3 $y2]
    set rect(7) [list 0 $y2 $x1 $y3]
    set rect(8) [list $x1 $y2 $x2 $y3]
    set rect(9) [list $x2 $y2 $x3 $y3]

    #iterate thru squares, x for 1, o for 2
    for {set i 1} {$i < 10} {incr i} {
        if {$squares(s$i) == 1} {
            drawX $rect($i) #This part is troubling
        } elseif {$squares(s$i) == 2} {
            .whole.board create oval $rect($i)
        }
    }

proc drawX {x1 y1 x2 y2} {
    .whole.board create line $x1 $y1 $x2 $y2 -width 3 -fill red
    .whole.board create line $x2 $y1 $x1 $y2 -width 3 -fill red
}
```

Basically, I am getting the error `wrong # args: should be "drawX x1 y1 x2 y2`. I don't understand whether my function arguments are incorrect or if I am passing the parameter in incorrectly.

Comment: Is this a different question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29887255/tk-tcl-trouble-understanding-this-tic-tac-toe-code-snippet -- I really can't tell

Comment: Yes. In that question, I am asking about the nature of several variables I found in someone else's code. In this one, I am passing parameters in incorrectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not use the correct number of arguments.

```
drawX $rect($i)
```

This is a function call with just one argument. If you want to expand those arguments, you need to use the expand operator on it (8.5+).

```
drawX {*}$rect($i)
```

In older versions that can be done with some `eval` magic.

Comment: So would I be passing in a list as one parameter if there wasn't an expansion operator?

Comment: @Renren29 Yes, exactly that. However, the `$canvas create line` operation (and all the other item constructors) can take the coordinates as a single list too; having them separate is forced by your procedure. Which might be a sensible thing, to be honest…